# Change label and position of media in store views via API

Tags: magento2, api, media, gallery

I encountered a problem today while saving images via the API: **catalogProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementV1**. The label and position of the image for all the store views except the default one are set to null because they are not a global scope and I don't understand how I can set all the fields as the same as the default one. Is there any way to do this?

What I see:

- default store view -> `image label: abc;  image position: 1;`
- second    store view  -> `image label: null; image position: null;`

What I want to see:

- default store view -> `image label: abc;  image position: 1;`
- second store view  -> `image label: abc; image position: 1;`